# Post back data to api without forcing a render component to do it all

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component for voting things up and down that I am trying to use to post data back with.  For example, button to vote up, button to vote down, changes internal state to record vote up or down.

[image: up and down votes]

Now it has come time to post the data changes back to an api.  This component is pretty much a render component:

```
<Feedbackify up={44} down={23} />
```

So you feed it the current state of votes and it just renders them and currently it modifies it's own internal state when you vote up or down.
I could just POST or PUT to the api from internally in the component, but I'd prefer not to.  What is the most idiomatic way pass some way to post in to the component from the outside?

```
<Feedbackify up={44} down={23} onChange={someOnChange}/>
```

Or are there alternative approaches in react that are cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to [list state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). So parent component has state with up and down votes, pass to `Feedbackify` only values for votes and `someOnChange` (as you do). On each vote change (on `someOnChange` call), state of the parent is changed and updated votes passed as props to `Feedbackify`. Also parent is responsible for sendeing data to api.

Example

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor (p) {
        super (p);
        this.state = {
            up: 0,
            down: 0
        }
    }

    someOnChange (event) {
        let { up, down } = this.state;
        // Assuming value will be positive for upvote and negative for downvote
        if (event.target.value > 0)
            up += event.target.value;
        else
            down += event.target.value;

        doAsyncPost (up, down); // Post to server API
        this.setState ({ up, down });
    }

    render () {
        return <Feedbackify up={this.state.up} down={this.state.down} onChange={this.someOnChange.bind(this)}/>
    }
}
```

Futher you may consider [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for managing state centrally for all components